# Tornado 5.0.2 with Python 3.5.3 - accessing tornado from separate thread

Tags: python, multithreading, callback, tornado, python-3.5

the problem is about the exception:

> An exception of type RuntimeError occured. Arguments: ("There is no current event loop in thread '......'.",)"

I have an application that is able to run fine in Python 2.7.13 with same tornado release but show the above error in Python 3.5.3. after reading for some time around the web I've discovered that the problem is about to calling the *write_message()* method from another thread, other than the original ioloop thread.

Searching for a solution got me to solve this issue by means of the *add_callback* method as shown into the code reported below.

Is my approach is correct or is there a more correct, elegant way to perform this thing?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys

import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.websocket
#import tornado.ioloop
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
import tornado.web
import socket

import threading

import time

# ----------------------------------------
# GLOBAL VARIABLE SECTION
# ----------------------------------------
clients=[]
exitGlobalFlag = False
io_loop=None

# ----------------------------------------
# TORNADO HANDLER
# ----------------------------------------
class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True

    def open(self):
        global clients

        print("New connection was opened from " + self.request.remote_ip)
        print("Path: " + self.request.path)
        self.write_message("Welcome to my websocket!")

        if self not in clients:
            clients.append(self)

    def on_message(self, message):
        global exitGlobalFlag

        print("Incoming message: "+message)
        self.write_message("["+self.request.remote_ip+"] You said: " + message)
        if (message == "WEBMSG:QUIT"):
            exitGlobalFlag = True
            self.stopTornado()
        elif (message == "WEBMSG:LOGOUT"):
            self.onCloseWrapper()
        else:
            pass

    def onCloseWrapper(self):
        print("LOGOUT command received...")
        self.close()

    def on_close(self):
        global clients
        print("Connection was closed...")
        if self in clients:
            clients.remove(self)

    def stopTornado(self):
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()

# ----------------------------------------
# Thread
# ----------------------------------------
class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter

    def send_msg_web(self, counter):
        """

        This is the code that need to use the write_message inside the Tornado server.
        Counter is used only to show how pass arguments.
        """
        global clients

        # For every active client I'll send a message
        for client in clients:
            try:
                msg='(Thread: ' + self.name + ') Say hello!!! counter: ' + str(counter)
                client.write_message(msg) # No exception arise now
            except tornado.websocket.WebSocketClosedError:
                msg="("+caller+") WebSocketClosedError exception!"
                print (msg)
            except Exception as e:
                msg="("+caller+")" + e.__doc__
                print (msg)
            pass

    def call(self, cbfn, *args):
        """

        This function is basically a wrapper and is used to 
        set the callback function that will be called
        directly into the next Tornado loop cycle.
        In this example the callback function take an argument but
        can be extended to many arguments as needed by simply
        adding the needed args[] instructions, in this case only one
        argument is taken so only args[0] is specified.
        """
        global io_loop

        ioloop = io_loop
        ioloop.add_callback(cbfn, args[0])  # cbfn is the function that will called and in this example take one argument

    def run(self):
        global clients

        counter = 0

        print ('Thread: ' + self.name + ' is starting ')

        # Main loop of the thread that have to perform
        # some stuff with the client connected to the
        # Tornado web server, active client are stored
        # inside the global array clients
        while not(exitGlobalFlag):
            time.sleep(1)
            self.call(self.send_msg_web, counter) # This is the wrapper for the function that will be called by Tornado
            counter+=1

# ----------------------------------------
# MAIN APPLICATION
# ----------------------------------------

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Set the tornado server
    application = tornado.web.Application([(r'/ws', WSHandler),])
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(8888)

    myIP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    print("Websocket Server Started at: " + myIP)

    # Define the tornado IOLoop
    io_loop = IOLoop.current()

    # Run the thread that will use the Tornado write_message
    thread1 = myThread(1, "Thread-1", 1)
    thread1.start()

    # Start the Tornado IOLoop
    io_loop.start()

    # Exiting from application
    print("Quit application!")

    # Force closing of all running thread before exit
    exitGlobalFlag = True

    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: As an update to my previous post I'll just ask why in Python2 is possible to call directly the _write_message_ from another thread without get any errors and why the execution in Python3 with the callback approach seems slowly than into Python3. I know that Python3 is slighty slower than Python2 but I can see a not trascurable discrepance in behaviour from Python2 and Python3. Thank to help me to better understand!

Comment: There are others ways, more Pythonic and efficient, to perform the task shown above (send a message to a Tornado client handler from a different thread than the one of Tornado)? Thank!